# Boto3 Dynamodb list_append Invalid type for parameter ExpressionAttributeNames type: <class 'set'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Error message is throwing me.  I have update_item updating an existing list.  When I put everything in the UpdateExpression, it works fine.  When I use the equivalent with ExpressionAttributeNames, I get the error in the title.  They look equivalent to me, but hopefully someone can point out my error.

This works fine:

```
update_resp = table.update_item(Key={
            'client': client,
            'run_date': today
        },
            UpdateExpression=f"SET results.{test_id}.trial_area = list_append(results.{test_id}.trial_area, :r)",
            ExpressionAttributeValues={':r': prior_test_results})
```

This gives the error:

```
update_resp = table.update_item(Key={
            'client': client,
            'run_date': today
        },
            UpdateExpression=f"SET #res = list_append(#res, :r)",
            ExpressionAttributeNames= {'#res', f'results.{test_id}.trial_area'},
            ExpressionAttributeValues={':r': prior_test_results})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB interprets a dot in an expression attribute name as a literal character within an attribute's name, rather than as a hierarchical separator. See the [Nested Attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html#Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.NestedAttributes) documentation.

You need to indicate multiple expression attribute name parts, for example

```
"#res": "results",
"#test": test_id,
"#trial": "trial_area"
```

and then use `#res.#test.#trial` in your expression.

Arguably this offsets any advantage you were hoping to get by making the expression shorter, but it should at least solve the problem of hierarchical naming.